# pythonの正規表現でn個目のカンマを削除する

Tags: python, 正規表現

```
x = '項目1,項目2,氏,名,年齢,住所,備考'
```

氏,名の間の`,`を消したい。

```
re.sub(r'','',X)
```

ご教示よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 正規表現は使いませんが、`lst = x.split(',')` として、`','.join(lst[0:3]) + ','.join(lst[3:])` など。

Comment: 一度分解してつなぎ合わせるのですね！結果は同じくできました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3個目のカンマだけをグループから除外する方法です。

```
import re
x = '項目1,項目2,氏,名,年齢,住所,備考'
re.sub('^(([^,]+,[^,]*){2}),(.+)$', '\\1\\3', x)
```

Comment: やっと解決しました。ありがとうございました。